# Magento REST api authentication

Tags: api, magento, rest, oauth, authorization

Is there a way to pass login credentials from code instead of entering credentials everytime in the popup for login authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont require login credentials every time for authorization,you'll get an access token and access secret upon successfull authorization by OAuth,use the later for further calls to the API.Oauth protocol works this way.

I guess Magento is using OAuth 1.0/1.0a,so everytime you'll authorize a user you get,

**oauth_token** - the Access Token that provides access to protected resources.

**oauth_token_secret** - the secret that is associated with the Access Token.

Comment: Is there any time duration for the validity of the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret ?

Comment: I used the oauth_token and oauth_token secret for my further calls it worked fine but moment I cleared all cache and cookies it said access denied for subsequent requests.

Comment: mostly for OAuth 1.0/1.0a there is no time duration validity

Comment: After clearing the cache and cookies of the browser it said {"messages":{"error":[{"code":403,"message":"Access denied"}]}}, I used the same oauth_token and oauth_token_secret

Comment: check the access token is still valid,refer http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_configuration.html

Comment: How to get the access token and secret stored on magento oauth server?

Comment: Is there any http authentication method available?

I don't want to use oauth authentication to get authorization. Is there any other method availble?

Comment: How to get token & token secret from consumer key & consumer-secret using chrome postman. I am requesting token & token secret [http//magentohost/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=http://httpbin.org/get] , get an error message oauth_problem=signature_invalid

Comment: Great Suggestions

Comment: @Cris Can you help me regard rest api customer getting error : https://snag.gy/MVINwS.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use OAUTH based authentication. Then pass the request token along with each request:

Refer: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html

Comment: I am using Magento REST API

Comment: I am using Oauth for this, only thing that I wanted was how to pass user credentials to the authorization url so that it does not prompt the user for each request to enter his credentials and then click on authorize.Code url:  
header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);

Comment: I know this is old, but did you end up using the php script they have or something else?