# Automatically login Magento OAuth with Java

Tags: java, magento, rest, oauth

I'm trying to login automatically in the REST Services of Magento. Everything just works fine. Except I always need to enter the authorizations URL manually. I'm trying to find a service or something were I can put the authorizations URL and get the verification code back from it. Without doing it manually.

I used this code/tutorial: http://blog.jerrysapps.com/2012/11/05/using-the-magento-rest-api-in-java-with-scribe/

Thanks.

edit: Now you need to do the Authorization step manually, you need to click on a button to 'approve' and need to be logged in to the back-end of Magento. I want to do this automatically. So the step of authorization and the loggin to the backend needs to be automatically

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood your question - please elaborate.

Comment: Edited the first posts zaske

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this:
[Magento REST api authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152764/magento-rest-api-authentication)

You should keep the oauth_token and the oauth_token_secret.
If you're using java, you may take a look at scribe:
https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java

Magento pull request:
https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/pull/325

Magento connection:
https://github.com/saleram1/scribe-java/commit/7fef61789236d4dff183bb35ff5ce3a5a01c153a

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way to go but this worked for me.
As I understood the Magento tokens don't expire. They can be manually revoked though.
Scribe (mentioned in other answer) was the easiest way I could find to to get authorization.
I also use a very handy library, Xstream, with a small FileUtil class, for storing and retrieving the token and service object to/from xml, so that I don't have to authorize and get new token each time. Maybe not the best practices used and some unecessary code but it requires one time authorization only. First I use the createService() and then the start() method from Authorization class.
Below are the Java classes used:

MagentoApi.java

```
package somepackage;

import org.scribe.builder.api.DefaultApi10a;
import org.scribe.model.Token;

public class MagentoApi extends DefaultApi10a {

private static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "http://domain.com/admin/oauth_authorize";

@Override
public String getAccessTokenEndpoint() {
    return "http://domain.com/oauth/token";
}

@Override
public String getRequestTokenEndpoint() {
    return "http://domain.com/oauth/initiate";
}

@Override
public String getAuthorizationUrl(Token requestToken) {
    return AUTHORIZE_URL+"?oauth_token="+requestToken.getToken();
}

}
```

Authorization.java

```
package somepackage;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder;
import org.scribe.model.Token;
import org.scribe.model.Verifier;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService;


public class Authorization {

private OAuthService service;
private Token requestToken;
private Token accessToken;
private String authUrl;

public Token start() {

    File f = new File("token.xml");
    if (f.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Feching Existing Token");
        loadToken();
        return accessToken;
    }

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("--- Magento OAuth Authorization ---\n");
    System.out.println("Fetching The Request Token...");
    requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
    System.out.println("Got The Request Token!\n");
    System.out.println(" Go & Authorize Magento Here:");
    authUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
    System.out.println(authUrl);
    System.out.println("\nPaste The Verifier Here:");
    System.out.print(">> ");
    Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println("\nTrading The Request Token For An Access Token...");
    accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
    System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
    saveToken();
    return accessToken;
}

public OAuthService createService() {

    File f = new File("service.xml");
    if (f.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Feching Existing Service");
        loadService();
        return service;
    }
    service = new ServiceBuilder()
            .provider(MagentoApi.class)
            .apiKey("Consumer Key")
            .apiSecret("Consumer Secret")
            .build();
    saveService()
    return service;
}

 public void saveService() {
    File file = new File("service.xml");
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("service", OAuthService.class);
    String xml = xstream.toXML(service);
    try {
        FileUtil.saveFile(xml, file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public void saveToken() {
    File file = new File("token.xml");
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("token", Token.class);
    String xml = xstream.toXML(accessToken);

    try {
        FileUtil.saveFile(xml, file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void loadService() {

    File file = new File("service.xml");
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("service", OAuthService.class);
    try {
        String xml = FileUtil.readFile(file);
        service = (OAuthService) xstream.fromXML(xml);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void loadToken() {

    File file = new File("token.xml");
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("token", Token.class);
    try {
        String xml = FileUtil.readFile(file);
        accessToken = (Token) xstream.fromXML(xml);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

}
```

FileUtil.Java

```
package somepackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class FileUtil {

private static final Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

public static String readFile(File file) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file.toPath(), CHARSET);
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuffer.append(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}

public static void saveFile(String content, File file) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file.toPath(), CHARSET);
    writer.write(content, 0, content.length());
    writer.close();
}
}
```

Comment: If I were to deploy these codes into a WAR file and send to production server, how am i going to keep the Verifier Code first time authenticated with Magento? Which node of token.xml or service.xml i should paste the Verifier code into it?